# What does "working as a flower a-ranger" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, interpretation

I remember reading the following comment thread below the scifi.se question "[How did the Rangers of the North make a living in the Lord of the Rings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255127/7533)":

> *[4 upvotes]* Working as a flower a-ranger - User1
>
> *[2 upvotes]* @User1: flagged - User2
>
> *[1 upvotes]* @User2: For making a bad pun? - User1

*(I apologize for any errors. I transcribe this from memory since the comments seem to have been deleted. Anyone with mod rights on scifi.se, feel free to fix any mistakes.)*

Judging from the conversion and the upvotes, (a) User1 was making a pun (**"Working as a flower a-ranger"**), which (b) a few people found funny, but which (c) User2 and a few others found offensive (or flag-worthy for some other reason).

Why is it funny and/or offensive? I understand English fairly well, but it's not my main language and I don't live in an English-speaking country, so there might be some cultural reference that eludes me. To be honest, I can't even make grammatical sense of the phrase. Google wasn't helpful.

Comment: Wasn't it "working as a flower a-ranger"?

Comment: Was it actually flagged? Because it's a pretty common "joke" to react to bad puns in comment sections with a "flagged" comment, but not really clicking on the button.

Comment: @JamesK: Ah, yes, that was it. I'll fix it in the question, since it won't invalidate your answer.

Comment: Maybe it's my dirty mind, but I can maybe see how 'a-ranger' can be considered offensive if you see it as 'a**-ranger' (i.e. a homophobic slur, we have similar expressions in British English)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't see the context of the *only* example, and there's no reason to suppose that particular example is anything to do with someone being "offended" anyway (the user who posted the word "flagged" was probably either being facetious or simply calling for an "irrelevant" weak pun to be deleted).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No objection from my side. Should I try to improve the question (remove the assumption of it being offensive) or is it just not a good fit for the site (I don't think I can delete it, though, once it has an upvoted/accepted answer)?

Comment: I don't think you *can* "improve" the question unless you can give us a link to the original online interchange. There's no real point in people here trying to guess exactly what caused that user to type "flagged" (the implication is that ***even the other user didn't know***, and he was actually there at the time! :). People write all sorts of meaningless drivel online, and unless you can find multiple instances of the same usage, you shouldn't assume it's necessarily either desirable or *possible* to figure out exactly what some "unusual / unclear" utterance actually "means".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is offensive; it's just not very funny.

The pun is on the words "ranger" and "arranger", and suggesting that the rangers could have made money by being (flower) arrangers: ie artists who create flower displays for various events.

It's flagged as "No longer needed" (comments can be flagged if they are "outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.") A weak pun is not really needed as a comment and a mod might delete on that basis.

I don't see any evidence of anyone being offended.  Flagging doesn't mean offence.

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious now, and I don't understand how I could have missed it. I think it *is* funny, actually, now that I get it.